# Can you compare multiple variables to see if they all equal the same value in JS?

Tags: javascript, compare, equals

Working in Javascript, I am trying to see if 5 different variables all contain the same value at a given time.  The value could be 1 of 6 things, but I need to see if they are all the same regardless of which value it is.  I have tried this:

```
if (die1 == die2 & die1 == die3 & die1 == die4 & die1 == die5) {
    yahtzeeQualify == true;
}
```

and this:

```
if (die1 == die2 == die3 == die4 == die5) {
    yahtzeeQualify == true;
}
```

Are either of these valid?  If so, there is probably an error in my code somewhere else...if not, I'd really appreciate some help.  I also have these variables in an array called dieArray as follows:

```
var dieArray = [die1, die2, die3, die4, die5];
```

It would be cool to learn a way to do this via the array, but if that isn't logical then so be it.  I'll keep trying to think of a way on my own, but up until now I've been stuck...

Comment: `[die1, die2, die3, die4, die5].every(Object.is.bind(0,die1))`

Comment: `!![die1, die2, die3, die4, die5].sort().toString().match(/(\w+)(,?\1){4}/)`

Comment: `var same=[die1, die2, die3, die4, die5].sort();same=same[0]==same[4];`

Comment: `RegExp([die2, die3, die4, die5]).test(Array(5).join(die1+","))`

Answer (score 7):

> Are either of these valid?

They are "valid" (as in this is executable code) but they don't perform the computation you want. You want to use a [logical AND (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_(.26.26)) not a bitwise AND.

The second one is just wrong. You run into type coercion issues and end up comparing `die1` to either `true` or `false`.

> It would be cool to learn a way to do this via the array

You can use [**`Array#every`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and compare whether each element is equal to the first one:

```
if (dieArray.every(function(v) { return v === dieArray[0]; }))
// arrow functions make this nicer:
// if (dieArray.every(v => v === dieArray[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with the Array.reduce:

```
var values = [die1, die2, die3, die4, die5];

var yahtzeeQualify = values.reduce(function(memo, element) {
   return element === values[0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st one is what you want, but it's messed up. You want `&&` not `&`

The 2nd one is logically wrong.

To do it with an array

```
yahtzeeQualify = dieArray.every(function(n){ return n === dieArray[0] })
```

Comment: Why is the second one logically wrong, its not loggically wrong, but its also not valid Javascript

Comment: @RFVenter it's logically wrong because die1==die2 is true or false. then you're comparing that to die3 which makes no sense

Comment: OK my mistake, so a ==b == c is valid javascript?