# Appropriate way to check if 4 strings are duplicated in JS

Tags: javascript

I have four fields in my form and I would like to know if these fields are duplicated and apply validation messages to each of the duplicated fields.

For example:

```
if (field1 === field2) {
    errors.field1 = 'Duplicated';
    errors.field2 = 'Duplicated';
}


if (field1 === field3 === field4) {
    errors.field1 = 'Duplicated';
    errors.field3 = 'Duplicated';
    errors.field4 = 'Duplicated';
}
```

What can be an elegant solution, if I have four fields?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you compare multiple variables to see if they all equal the same value in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711396/can-you-compare-multiple-variables-to-see-if-they-all-equal-the-same-value-in-js)

Comment: Was about to answer: If you put the values in an array first, you can do some fun comparisons.

eg:

    var fields = [field1, field2, field3, field4];
    if (count(array_unique(fields)) === 1)){
       // all values are equal
    }

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26634125/3093731